# make the moving bits more efficient

Tags: c

in our company's latest project, we want to move a char arry to left half a byte, e.g.

```
char buf[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x21}
```

we want to make the buf like

```
0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x82, 0x10
```

how do I make the process more efficient, can you make the time complexity less than O(N) if there are N bytes to be processed?

```
SOS...
```

Comment: More efficient than what? And no, you can't do better than O(N).

Comment: Are we prematurely optimizing again?

Comment: you can try casting them as a `int64_t`, and shift them 8 bytes at a time instead of 1

Comment: @TaylorFlores yes, but don't forget about endianess

Comment: @IlyaBursov: and alignment.

Comment: Yeah, but both of those issues can easily be handled by just a little bit of code.

Comment: @TaylorFlores they can be handled, but final performance could be worst than obvious solution, I'm not stating this, just thoughts

Comment: @JonathonReinhart We definitely are.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Also, why would you cast to int64_t? You most definitely don't want a signed integer type when doing bit-wise operations. And those are 32 bits, not 64. So it would be uint32_t if anything.

Comment: @Lundin okay, `uint64_t`. And I suggested 64 bit integers because I was assuming that the buffer could be larger than 4 bytes. The OP *did* say `N` bytes

Comment: you can do better than N, ~1 if you just use a union with a bitfield and attribute packed, something like: `union hack{char orig[N+1],struct shifted{char offset:4;char new[N]}}`

Comment: Hi technosaurus, I have also tried using Bit-fields but failed. can you give the solution in details. thanks very much...

Comment: Hi technosaurus, I write the following code according to your ideal.

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>

#define N 8

typedef union
{
        char orig[N + 1];
        struct
        {
                char offset:4;
                char new[N];
        }shifted;
}hack;

void printBuf(const char *title, const char *buf, int len)
{
        int i = 0;
        printf("%s\n", title);
        for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
                printf("0x%02x ", buf[i]);
        printf("\n");
}

Comment: int main()
{
        char buf[N] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
        hack h;
        memcpy(h.orig, buf, N);
        printBuf("orig", h.orig, N);
        printBuf("shifted", h.shifted.new, N);
        return 0;
}

Comment: In my ubuntu system, print: orig
0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 
shifted
0x34 0x56 0x78 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 0xffffff90

Comment: @user2910047 try adding __attribute__((packed)) to force the bitfields to but up against the next byte, but you need gcc >= 4.4 ... did I mention it is implementation dependent

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that it is implemented dependent on endiannes...the evils of endianness.

Comment: @user2910047: Endianness to a degree but in your case more to do with padding and alignment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It may not compile well due to alignment, but you can try using a bitfield offset in a struct.

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) shifted{
 char offset:4; // dump data
 char data[N]; // rest of data
};
```

or on some systems

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) shifted{
 char offset:4; // dump data
 char data[N]; // rest of data
 char last:4; // to make an even byte
};

struct shifted *shifted_buf=&buf;
//now operate on shifted_buf->data
```

Or you can try making it a union

```
union __attribute__((packed)) {
  char old[N];
  struct{
    char offset:4;
    char buf[N];
    char last:4; // to make an even byte
  }shifted;
}data;
```

The alternative would be to cast to an array of int and <<4 for each int, reducing it to N/4, but this is dependent on endianness.

Comment: according to your first method :                                  char buf[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
struct new *shifted = &buf;
and we got shifted.data: 0x34 0x56 0x78 0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 0x00                                                                my test machine is Ubuntu 4.4.3

Comment: @user2910047 - I added padding at the end to force it to fit to an even byte, but it will still be implementation dependent.

Comment: OMG this is terrible. This is just terrible. `struct new`, seriously? `__attribute__((packed))` and a 4-bit bitfield? Argh...

Comment: yeah "new" is a keyword in other C derived languages (replaced), first word that popped into my head for the "new" data, and all of the attribute* extensions are a PITA, but if it works...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In C89 at least. (in C99, it has a well-defined behavior, but it's not any better than `memcpy()`, and why bother with all of this if we can have bit operations?)

Comment: @H2CO3: Oh, what, C? What am I doing here?!

Comment: Please attention that the tagged is C... sorry for taking you so much time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit LOL, indeed, this is C. You can find a vomit bag over there.

Answer (score 3):

Without more context, I would go even as far as questioning the need for an actual array. If you have 4 bytes, that can easily be represented using a `uint32_t`, and then you can perform an `O(1)` shift operation:

```
uint32_t x = 0x12345678;
uint32_t offByHalf = x << 4;
```

This way, you would replace array access with bit masking, like this:

```
array[i]
```

would be equivalent with

```
(x >> 8 * (3 - i)) & 0xff
```

And who knows, arithmetic may even be faster than memory access. **But don't take my word for it, benchmark it.**

Comment: I have tried that but failed if the machine have different byte-order. and the bytes to be processed are much bigger that 4 bytes.

Comment: @user2910047 Arithmetic operations don't depend on endianness.

Comment: I suppose the OP means the actual filling of the uint32_t, which does depend on endianess. If you just make a memcpy or a union from the char array to the uint32_t, it would give problems. But such code could be written in an endian-independent way instead: `x=0; x|=buf[0]<<24; x|=buf[1]<<16;` and so on.

Comment: @Lundin Why are you saying that? I was not `memcpy()`ing or type-punning anything. Intentionally. So I don't think OP was right about complaining that "this does not work", because it indeed **does** work.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry, I meant "the OP means", clarified the comment.

Comment: @Lundin Ah OK. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @H2CO3 As in, he has an array of bytes and he wants it stored in a uint32_t. He can't just hard code a literal and show it into an uint32_t.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, yes, that's true. Do you think I should incorporate that into the answer as well? (I think no because that was not the question.)

Comment: Actually, the question is shifting an array of N bytes by four bits. Your assumption that it's 4 bytes is just coincidental to the example given. I'll edit the question for the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you want to *actually* shift the array, you'll need to hit every element at least once so it'll be O(n). There's no getting around that. You can do it with something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void shiftNybbleLeft (unsigned char *arr, size_t sz) {
    for (int i = 1; i < sz; i++)
        arr[i-1] = ((arr[i-1] & 0x0f) << 4) | (arr[i] >> 4);
    arr[sz-1] = (arr[sz-1] & 0x0f) << 4;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char buf[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
    shiftNybbleLeft (buf, sizeof (buf));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (buf); i++)
        printf ("0x%02x ", buf[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

which gives you:

```
0x23 0x45 0x67 0x80
```

That's not to say you can't make it more efficient <sup>(a)</sup>. If you instead modify your extraction code so that it behaves differently, you can avoid the shifting operation.

In other words, don't shift the array, simply set an offset variable and use that to modify the extraction process. Examine the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char getByte (unsigned char *arr, size_t index, size_t shiftSz) {
    if ((shiftSz % 2) == 0)
        return arr[index + shiftSz / 2];
    return ((arr[index + shiftSz / 2] & 0x0f) << 4)
        | (arr[index + shiftSz / 2 + 1] >> 4);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char buf[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
    //shiftNybbleLeft (buf, sizeof (buf));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf ("buf[1] with left shift %d nybbles -> 0x%02x\n",
            i, getByte (buf, 1, i));
    return 0;
}
```

With `shiftSz` set to 0, it's as if the array isn't shifted. By setting `shiftSz` to non-zero, an O(1) operation, `getByte()` will actually return the element *as if* you had shifted it by that amount. The output is as you would expect:

```
Index 1 with left shift 0 nybbles -> 0x34
Index 1 with left shift 1 nybbles -> 0x45
Index 1 with left shift 2 nybbles -> 0x56
Index 1 with left shift 3 nybbles -> 0x67
```

Now that may seem a contrived example (because it is) but there's ample precedent in using tricks like that to avoid potentially costly operations. You'd probably also want to add some bounds checking to catch problems with referencing outside the array.

Keep in mind that there's a trade-off. What you gain by not having to shift the array may be offset to some degree by the calculations done during extraction. Whether it's actually worth it depends on how you use the data. If the arrays is large but you don't extract that many values from it, this trick may be worth it.

---

As another example of using "tricks" to prevent costly operations, I've seen text editors that don't bother shifting the contents of lines either (when deleting a character for example). Instead they simply set the character to a 0 code point and take care of it when displaying the line (ignoring the 0 code points).

They'll generally clean up eventually but often in the background where it won't interfere with your editing speed.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Though you may want to actually make sure this is *necessary.*

One of your comments stated that your arrays are about 500 entries in length and I can tell you that my not-supremely-grunty development box can shift that array one nybble to the left at the rate of about half a million times every single second.

So, even if your profiler states that a large *proportion* of time is being spent in there, that doesn't necessarily mean it's a large *amount* of time.

You should only look into optimising code if there's a specific, identified bottleneck.

Comment: Rether `return array[(index + offset) % array.length]`, and then it will be correct :)

Comment: But it's hard to apply this at the bit level, since the offset indexing is based on address calculcations. You'd need a bit-addressable computer, and those are ... rare, and even then it wouldn't be possible to express in standard C I think.

Comment: @unwind, you can quite easily do it with bitwise operations to get below-byte values. It's trickier but doable.

Comment: @H2CO3, that would be correct for a rotate operation but, based on the question, it's a pure shift (with a zero nybble coming in at the other end). No doubt the code given could be made much cleaner with bounds checking and such but that would needlessly complicate the answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo Fair enough. I've confused the two operations. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi paxdiablo, as the example shows, input buf may be {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78} and output buf is {0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x80}

Comment: of course the input buf length is about 500, and that can impact our system's performance after analyzing with gprof.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tackle the only objectively answerable part of the question, which is:

> can you make the time complexity less than O(N) if there are N bytes to be processed?

If you need the entire output array then no, you cannot do better than `O(N)`.

If you only need certain elements of the output array, then you can compute just those.

Comment: We want all the bytes after processing.